# Create a list of components with a select attribute

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to create a list component which I can put many mat-cards inside (or, probably, another component I will create with the necessary css for the select/deselect option).

I want those cards to be selectable, so it would change the background color and some other stuff when it's selected, but only one at a time, so if I click on another card the first one would be deselected. Also, I need to know which one is selected, by using an ID or something else, in a parent component that will use it.

How can I make such options? I'm kind of new to html...
Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after researching around:

So, I have three components here, I'll call them: **page.component**, **card-list.component** and **card.component**

The page component will call both the card-list and the card component and will fill the content of the card.

The other two components will work for the selection proccess to work on it's own without any need to worry about it in the page component.

So, the **page.component.html** should look like this, the *items* can be any list in the page.component.ts

```
<div *ngIf="items.length > 0">
     <card-list #itemsComponent>
         <card *ngFor="let item of items" [cardIdentifier]="item.id">            
             // Content
         </card>
     </card-list>
    
     <p>
         Option selected: {{itemsComponent.selectedComponent}}
     </p>
</div>
```

My **card.component.html** looks like this

```
<div (click)="cardClicked()">
  <mat-card id={{styleID}} class="deselected-card">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

And the **card.component.ts**

```
import { EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './card.component.scss'
  ],
})
export class CardComponent{

  @Input() cardIdentifier;
  @Output() objectClicked = new EventEmitter();
  styleID: string;
  private _selected: boolean;

  get selected(): boolean {
    return this._selected;
  }
  set selected(value: boolean) {
    this._selected = value;
    if (this.selected) {
      document.getElementById(this.styleID).classList.replace("deselected-card", "selected-card");
    }
    else {
      document.getElementById(this.styleID).classList.replace("selected-card", "deselected-card");
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.styleID = "card-" + this.cardIdentifier;
  }

  cardClicked() {
    this.selected = !this.selected;

    this.objectClicked.emit({ value: this })
  }
}
```

Lastly, the **card-list.component.html**

```
<div class="card-list">
  
  <ng-content (objectClicked)="onChildClicked($event)"></ng-content>

</div>
```

And the **card-list.component.ts**

```
selectedComponent;
@ContentChildren(CardComponent) templates: QueryList<CardComponent>;    
 
ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.templates.forEach((template) => {
    template.objectClicked.subscribe((event) => this.onChildClicked(event));
  });
}

onChildClicked(event) {    
  if (event.value.selected)
    this.selectedComponent = event.value.styleID;
  else
    this.selectedComponent = "";
}
```

Using those classes, it should work for a generic mat-card list.
I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but it worked for me